# Different action by prefix of URL

Tags: ios, swift, url

Here is my situation: i'm calling file locally on my ios application ( Running in Swift).

If the file is a jpg, one action happen, if the file is a mp4, another action happen.

For this i'musing this code:

```
    let urlString = "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    let fileName = urlString as NSString;
    let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";
    let fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let request = NSURLRequest.init(url: fileURL as URL)


    /* END DOWNLOAD + READ LOCALY */

    if (fileURL.pathExtension?.hasPrefix("jpg"))! {
        Swift.print("THIS IS A JPG")


    }
    else if (fileURL.pathExtension == "mp4") {

        Swift.print("THIS IS A MP4")

    }
```

This works perfectly.

What i need to do now is instead of calling th eifle locally, to calling it form an URL.

I read my file from an url by:

```
videoVRView.load(from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)")
```

Which work.

But from that, the action is not working, i've try the following:

```
 if ((from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)").hasPrefix("jpg"))! {
    Swift.print("THIS IS A JPG")


}
else if ((from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)") == "mp4") {

    Swift.print("THIS IS A MP4")

}
```

Without any success !!

Does anybody know how is this achievable ?

Thanks a lot =)

-- EDIT --

What im trying to do is th efollowing to resume:

at th emoment i call image locally via:

```
       imageVRView.load(UIImage(named: "\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)" ),
   of: GVRPanoramaImageType.stereoOverUnder)
```

I try instead to use:

```
imageVRView.load(UIImage(named: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)" ),
   of: GVRPanoramaImageType.stereoOverUnder)
```

Without success . . . .  I need to call the image via this method ... any idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: `hasPrefix` tests for patterns like `jpgFile` and `mp4Stream`. You need to look for suffix, not prefix. [`hasSuffix`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1541149-hassuffix).

Comment: Show the value of `posts[selectedIndexPath].link`.

Comment: You should check the url UTI type for local resources or the mimeType, `if mimeType.hasPrefix("image")` from the url response if not local.

Comment: @shallowThought the value is just a normal url such as www.mydomain.com/image.jpg

Comment: @LeoDabus How to integrate the MIMEtype in my code do you think ?

Comment: you can check the syntax at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/2303865

Comment: `www.mydomain.com/image.jpg` does not start with (prefix) `jpg`. Take @dasblinkenlights advice.

Comment: @shallowThought not every image link ends with the file type. for instance every dropbox link ends with dl=0 or dl=1   `https://www.dropbox.com/s/sk46eyglvijlrec/horse.jpg?dl=1`

Comment: @shallowThought im using firebase so path is like https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mydomain.appspot.com/o/01_07.jpeg?alt=media&token=c1c-8f77-b699904a475d

Answer (score 0):

You can make a URL request for the url header using the httpMethod HEAD to check your url mime type without the need to download the data first:

```
let link = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/sk46eyglvijlrec/horse.jpg?dl=1"
let url = URL(string: link)!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { _ , response , _ in
    guard let response = response, (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        print("mimeType", response.mimeType ?? "nil")            // image/jpeg
        print("suggestedFilename:", response.suggestedFilename ?? "no suggestedFilename")   // horse.jpg
        print("expectedContentLength:", response.expectedContentLength ?? "nil")   // 352614
        print("textEncodingName:", response.textEncodingName ?? "nil")
        print("url:", response.url ?? "nil")                 // "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/RNrhGtvroTLU1Gww7eQo1N1ePRiix68zsqZJ1xWPjKm3pmOUNQwNVntbPuFG4jZ8/file?dl=1"
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: thanks, seems i have no luck I'm using similar way at the beginning of my code .. . 

I've edit my questions, maybe it will help ? what i need is call url of an image via name method . .. 

Thanks a lot !