# How can you execute a URLRequest that doesn't have/need a response body?

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

Subject says it all. We want to make a `URLRequest` where all we care about is the HTTP return code (e.g. 200, 400, etc.) which we can get from the `httpUrlResponse` object. What we don't need is a response body, since there isn't one.

Here's how you make a request that expects a response body...

```
let urlRequest = [insert code to make request]
let urlSession = [insert code to make session]

let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {

    (responseBodyData, httpUrlResponse, error) in

    if let error = error {
        // handle error
        return
    }

    guard let responseBodyData = responseBodyData else {
        // Handle missing data
        return
    }
}

task.resume()
```

But how do you do it if you don't want/need `responseBodyData`?  Or do you just use the same code, ignoring the `responseBodyData` field, replacing it with `_` since it is optional and can be ignored?

Comment: Yeah, just ignore it.

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804274/2303865

Comment: @Matt, it wasn't a question about 'try it and see.'  I know that way works. What I'm wondering is if that's the *correct* way.  In other words, was there something else that didn't have that parameter--a different closure signature or something. But if there isn't and the correct behavior is just to ignore it, then that's good too.

Comment: Okay, that’s answerable, so I’ve answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> What I'm wondering is if that's the correct way. In other words, was there something else that didn't have that parameter--a different closure signature or something.

No. The closure signature is predefined: it *must* take three parameters. The names don’t matter, but the number does:

```
let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {(body, response, err) in
```

If you want to ignore the first parameter, ignore it (i.e. don’t refer to it again within the curly braces). You can, if you like, substitute an underscore to signal to yourself that you don’t care about the first parameter:

```
let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {(_, response, err) in
```

But there is no requirement that you do that; the compiler doesn’t care one way or the other.

Comment: That’s exactly what I ended up doing.